# Features based on different target platforms in a single p2 site

Tags: tycho

I have an internal p2 site with a number of different utility features we use in our products. I have just added a new set of plug-ins along with a new feature with utility functions for RAP (whereas the "old" functionality is for RCP/SWT).

In order to compile stuff, I use two different target platforms (one for RCP and a new one for RAP) and refer to these from the plug-ins and features. I have organized the modules so I have the usual two layers of parent POMs:

- ...parent - with all the common Tycho and Maven booking
- ...parent.rcp - container for all plug-ins that depends on/uses RCP/SWT functionality - also sets the target platform to include RCP/SWT features
- ...parent.rap - same for RAP

No problems there. Everything compiles and all tests runs.

I even have some of the existing plug-ins in both the features (RCP and RAP) as they don't depend on any UI functionality (e.g. OSGi test utilities). No problems there either.

But... when I try to make a single p2 update site with both the features (RCP and RAP), I run into a problem. I get the following message:

```
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: com.rcpcompany:com.rcpcompany.uibindings.updatesite:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ /Git/ui-bindings/com.rcpcompany.uibindings.updatesite/pom.xml
[INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
[INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
[INFO] {osgi.ws=gtk, osgi.os=linux, osgi.arch=x86, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true}
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: com.rcpcompany.uibindings.updatesite raw:3.0.0.'SNAPSHOT'/format(n[.n=0;[.n=0;[-S]]]):3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: com.rcpcompany.utils.rap.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'org.eclipse.rap.ui.forms 0.0.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: com.rcpcompany.uibindings.updatesite raw:3.0.0.'SNAPSHOT'/format(n[.n=0;[.n=0;[-S]]]):3.0.0-SNAPSHOT depends on: com.rcpcompany.utils.rap.feature.feature.group [1.0.0,1.0.1)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency from com.rcpcompany.utils.rap.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.qualifier to org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi [2.0.0,2.1.0).", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.rcpcompany.utils.rap.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.qualifier to org.eclipse.rap.rwt.testfixture [2.0.0,2.1.0).", "Unable to satisfy dependency from com.rcpcompany.utils.rap.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.qualifier to org.eclipse.rap.ui.forms 0.0.0.", "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."] -> [Help 1]
    ....
```

As the update project is associated with the RCP target platform, I understand the messages above such that Tycho (or p2) cannot find the plug-ins from the RAP target platform and complains.

(If I make two different update sites, everything works fine, but I don't want that :-/)

How can I convince Tycho to construct update site with both features? Do I have to make a combined target platform with all the possible dependencies or are there another way?

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with the obvious: The things that you want to aggregate into the p2 repository need to be in the [target platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform) because the build can only use things that are in the target platform. But this doesn't seem to be your problem - there is rather a problem with the dependencies of the things you want to aggregate.

[Currently](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=372780), the dependencies of the aggregated content also needs to be in the target platform. You should be able to create a joint RCP&RAP target platform by merging the configuration from both your parents.

Unfortunately, this isn't all yet: Currently, it also needs to be possible to install all your features at once. This is what Tycho simulates during dependency resolution: It pretends to do a p2 installation with the build result of a module. If you get a "cannot be installed at once" error during dependency resolution, you can may try to set the `target-platform-configuration` switch `allowConflictingDependencies` to `true`. This switch was originally introduced to support exactly your use case in the (now deprecated) `eclipse-update-site` packaging type. I'm not sure if it works for `eclipse-repository` though.

If it doesn't work, I only see the possibility to build two separate p2 repositories, and to combine them in an additional (post-)build step. You can either put both p2 repositories on your web server and group them logically using a so-called composite repository, or you copy ("mirror") the two repositories together using a [p2 mirror tool](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Additional_Tools).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For now I have opted for a solution where I first create two different p2 sites and them merge them together with the mirror goal of tycho-p2-extras-plugin. This works fine. The only thing, is that I have to keep the categories on the two site in sync, but as they very seldom change, that is ok...